# Call viewWillDisappear when user quits application ios

Tags: ios

I have an application that stores values in the `viewWillDisappear` method in one of my classes. For example, I store the data and time in the `viewWillAppear` method and the same again when in the `viewWillDisappear` method so I'm able to compare the time difference and log this out.

However, if the user presses the home button on the device, then the `viewWillDisappear` code is not run. I've tried to call this particular method in the `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but this stores the wrong information as the `viewWillDisappear` method isn't actually run. I've also tried to store them in `NSUserDefaults`, but again, as the `viewWillDisappear` method isn't run, then the wrong values are stored.

Is there a way to make the `viewWillDisappear` method run for that view as soon as the user presses their home button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the viewWillAppear register for this notification...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(appEnteredBackground:)
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}

-(void)appEnteredBackground:(NSNotification *)appEnteredBackgroundNotification {

    //do your thing

}
```

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` both must call super at some point.